# How read complex json format using dataflow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Hi I have used data flow source output format is as below:

[image]

I want output as shown below:

[image]

Json format:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the required output, you can follow the procedure below:

Add a flatten transformation to the source and unroll it by `Table.rows`, as shown below:

[image]

Data preview of the flatten transformation:

[image]

Add a derived column transformation to the flatten transformation and create columns as follows:

- id: rows[1]
- city: rows[2]

[image]

Data preview of the derived column transformation:

[image]

Add a select transformation to obtain the required columns, as shown below:

[image]

Data preview of the selected column:

[image]